# Android on scroll up stop autoscroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have to edit a `ListView` so that the autoscroll stop when I scroll up and restart when I scroll completely down as it works in Android Studio's window Logcat for example. How can I implement it?

The `ListView` is set with `android: transcriptMode = "alwaysScroll"`.

Answer (score 1):

implement `OnScrollListener` and look on the `firstVisibleItem`. Store it somewhere, then when `onScroll` is called again compare `firstVisibleItem` with what you got stored. If it's greater => The user is scrolling down otherwise the user is scrolling up.

Comment: Practically `alwaysScroll`  will force the `listview` to scroll to bottom every time arrive a new element in my list and it is ok for me. The problem is that when I am scrolling up (e.g to read the value of some previous element of the list) I don't want that the list scroll down to the last element. But I want that this process restart only if I come back to the bottom of the list. I#m sorry, maybe I didn't formulate good my question